Is it possible to deconstruct safely, e.g. with named variables?
I like to use records and recently I start enjoying deconstructing record directly into properties, the one-liner looks really nice:
(instanceA.Property, instanceB.Property1, instanceB.Property2) = SomeMethodReturningRecord(...);

However, I am worrying about future refactoring, where record members may be reordered and if properties are of the same type, then such code is an easy source of bugs.
There are named arguments, which solve the ordering problem and help to make method refactoring safe.
Is there anything similar for deconstructing?

It would be cool to map names, something like (pseudo-code):
(a:instanceA.Property, b:instanceB.Property1, c:instanceB.Property2) = SomeMethodReturningRecordBla(...);
...
public record Bla(double a, double b, double c);


This doesn't seem to be supported by C# 12.0 or earlier. Why would your records change?

I often refactor methods arguments, so I may do similar to what method returns. Also deconstructing of records doesn't have much support from intellisense, the method help just shows Bla and not Bla(a, b, c) or something to have idea which property on the left side correspond to which of the record. Sure, I could first deconstruct into var (a, b, c) and then assign one by one, but that's not a one-liner, nor it's safe from reordering...

A good refactoring tool should reorder the deconstruction automatically.

Actually there is a intellisense support when mouseovering = sign. Then tooltip shown: void Bla.Deconstruct(out double a, out double b, out double c). At least something to check if left side matches.
